# Sharepoint Framework webpart loading time issues

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365, spfx, sharepointframework

I am facing some challenges in the loading time of the webpart(15 secs). I was pulling data from the list and binding it to the drop down control in ajax but it has some waiting time since async call is involved.

I need a better performance how this can be achieved. can anyone provide insights.

```
function getPackingSites()
{
var packagingSiteUrl = siteAbsUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+packingSiteList+"')/Items";
var packagingSiteOptions ="";
$.ajax({
url:packagingSiteUrl,
method: "Get",
async: false,
headers: {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
},
success: function (PackingSiteData) {
if (PackingSiteData.d.results.length > 0) {
for (var i = 0; i < PackingSiteData.d.results.length; i++) {
packagingSiteOptions += "<option value='"+PackingSiteData.d.results[i].ID+"'>"+PackingSiteData.d.results[i].Title+"</option>";
}
}
},
error: function (x, e) {
alert(e.message.tostring());
}
});
$("#PackingSiteDropdwn").html(packagingSiteOptions);

var tempLink = '<a id="newformSubmit" class="btn offset" href="'+siteAbsUrl+'/pages/Create.aspx?PackSiteID='+$("#PackingSiteDropdwn").val()+'&Source='+siteAbsUrl+'">Submit</a>';
$("#newformSubmitSpan").html(tempLink);
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to accomplish performance wise? Do you want to remove the Ajax call, or do you want an indication the Ajax is loading, or do you want to make the Ajax call faster (or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a sync call to render your webpart, this will increase webpart load time.

I suggest you use async data refresh, you could use react framework for this easily.

When webpart load first time, show tip information to users such as 'data loading', when async call data returned, display the actually data.

```
return (      
      <div className={ styles.fileViewCounter }>
        default content
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>              
              <table className="tree">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th className={styles.THWidth}>Folder/File</th>
                        <th >Views</th>
                        <th >Viewers</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                
                { this.state.FileViewResult
                    ? <tbody dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.FileViewResult}}></tbody>
                    : <tr><td align={"center"} colSpan={3}>Data Loading...</td></tr>
                 }                
            </table>          
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
```

You could check [github samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples) or [my demo project](https://github.com/OS-Lee/FileViewCounter) for async data refresh.

Comment: Hi Lee_MSFT,

The application is entirely based on No JS Framework so we coudn't able to move to react. In this case can you give some insight how to improve the performance

Comment: Use async:true would reduce webpart load time, update bind logic $("#PackingSiteDropdwn").html(packagingSiteOptions); in success function.

Comment: Hi Lee_MSFT as suggessted i have updated the code but it doesnt improve the performance.

Comment: are there any other api calls involved? with async:false?

Answer (score 0):

Is fetching the items from search an option for you?